# Code for keeping an image, ad fixed at one place on the screen

Tags: html, css

In order to do so, do i have to merge code with the html code of the ad,image..is there any way or a code for keeping a part of the screen fixed( that remains unaffected by scrolling) irrespective of whatsoever element is there on that space.

Answer (score 0):

You can do image and ad portion fixed by assigning position style in your css file like:

```
img {position:fixed;}
```

Comment: i was wondering if it's possible to do so without merging img {position:fixed;} code with the image, ad code.

Comment: i want to keep a SPACE fixed...something that doesn't has a code.

Comment: can you please provide your question with code that you wrote!! or explain in details what exactly you want?? 
Or if you can use bootstrap then you can add class="affix" in your perticular div!!!

Comment: keeping a "space" fixed... You can't keep "nothing" fixed. What you want is to keep a certain element (e.g. a div or img or whatever) fixed. Therefore you would only have to adapt the code above to match the right elements. The solutions is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at layouting with CSS. More specifically the `position` property.
In your case you could define a CSS class as follows and assign it to your element:

```
.makeMeFix {
   position:fixed,
   bottom: 0px,
   left: 0px,
   width: 30px,
   height: 30px
}
```

This would cause an element to be of size 30x30px that is fixed in the lower left corner.
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score 0):

Add position fixed and modify its position using css top, left, right, or bottom

```css
.img-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <!-- Put image here -->
</div>

<div class="text-content-container">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  <p>t is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
  <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>
  <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</p>
</div>
```